# Running concatenated commands fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile

While trying to build the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine3.12

RUN apk update && \
    apk --no-cache add git

# Install Syslog
RUN wget -O /usr/remote_syslog_linux_i386.tar.gz https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/releases/download/v0.20/remote_syslog_linux_i386.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf /usr/remote_syslog_linux_i386.tar.gz -C /usr
```

I get the following error

[image]

However, the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine3.12

RUN apk update && \
    apk --no-cache add git

# Install Syslog
RUN wget -O /usr/remote_syslog_linux_i386.tar.gz https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/releases/download/v0.20/remote_syslog_linux_i386.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf /usr/remote_syslog_linux_i386.tar.gz -C /usr
```

doesn't run into any error.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is reproducible. The `tar` command is failing, but works if I make slight changes like using a separate `RUN` statement or inserting a `ls -l` debugging printout. How bizarre!